# Calling sub from workbook not working on CountIf condition

Tags: excel, vba

I've a sub that fills month sheets counting from another closed workbooks.
I've tested the following sub in vba console and works. Once i call the sub from a button in the excel sheet it doesn't work only on the countif condition.

```
Public Sub Contatore()

Dim month, m
Dim loc, l
Dim file As Variant
Dim names As Range
Dim n As Range
Dim buttonName As String

'buttonName = Trim(Application.Caller)
Set names = Range("A2:A67")
Set month = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set loc = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
month.Add "Gennaio", "-01-2022"
month.Add "Febbraio", "-02-2022"
month.Add "Marzo", "-03-2022"
month.Add "Aprile", "-04-2022"
month.Add "Maggio", "-05-2022"
month.Add "Giugno", "-06-2022"
month.Add "Luglio", "-07-2022"
month.Add "Agosto", "-08-2022"
month.Add "Settembre", "-09-2022"
month.Add "Ottobre", "-10-2022"
month.Add "Novembre", "-11-2022"
month.Add "Dicembre", "-12-2022"
loc.Add "2", "A97:V98" 
loc.Add "3", "A100:V101" 
loc.Add "5", "A103:V104"
loc.Add "7", "A106:V107" 
loc.Add "6", "A109:V110" 
loc.Add "8", "A112:V113" 
loc.Add "4", "A115:V116" 

file = Dir("C:\Users\nome\Desktop\Test\*.xls?")
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    While (file <> "")
        For m = 0 To month.Count - 1
                    If InStr(file, month.Items()(m)) > 0 Then

                    'If buttonName = month.keys()(m) Then

                        Set wb = GetObject("C:\Users\nome\Desktop\Test\" & file)
                            For Each n In names
                                For l = 0 To loc.Count - 1
                                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(month.keys()(m)).Cells(n.Row, CLng(loc.keys()(l))) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(month.keys()(m)).Cells(n.Row, CLng(loc.keys()(l))).Value + Application.CountIf(wb.Sheets("Modello 44").Range(loc.Items()(l)), n)
                                Next
                            Next
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                    'End If
                    End If

        Next
                    file = Dir
    Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: I really tried, but your statement is far to complex for my little brain. Why don't you split such statements into pieces - set the month name into a variable, the source- and destrange into variables, the result of `CountIf` into a variabe and so on. That helps to understand the code and to see where an error happens. Also: Why do you use `GetObject` instead of `Workbooks.Open` ?

Comment: i need to use 2 dictionaries in order to coordinate other workbooks to the counter one. I've tried the Workbooks.Open but still not working...

Comment: `Set names = Range("A2:A67")` really needs a specific workbook and worksheet to make sure you're not just picking up from the ActiveSheet...

Comment: Just recognized before opening this page.... solved. Thanks Tim

Answer (score 0):

Fully-qualify your range for `names` (also a suggestion for using Format in place of the first Dictionary)

```vb
Public Sub Contatore()
    
    Const F_PATH As String = "C:\Users\nome\Desktop\Test\"
    Dim month As String, m As Long, dt As Date
    Dim locs, loc
    Dim file As Variant
    Dim names As Range
    Dim n As Range
    
    Set names = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("NameHere").Range("A2:A67") '<<< really needs a full workbook/worksheet qualifier
    
    Set locs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    locs.Add "2", "A97:V98"
    locs.Add "3", "A100:V101"
    locs.Add "5", "A103:V104"
    locs.Add "7", "A106:V107"
    locs.Add "6", "A109:V110"
    locs.Add "8", "A112:V113"
    locs.Add "4", "A115:V116"

    file = Dir(F_PATH & "*.xls?")
    While file <> ""
        For m = 1 To 12
            dt = DateSerial(2022, m, 1)
            If InStr(file, Format(dt, "-mm-yyyy")) > 0 Then
                month = Format(dt, "mmmm") 'month name
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(F_PATH & file)
                For Each n In names.Cells
                    For loc = 0 To locs.Count - 1
                        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(month).Cells(n.Row, CLng(loc.keys()(loc)))
                            .Value = .Value + Application.CountIf(wb.Sheets("Modello 44").Range(loc.Items()(loc)), n.Value)
                        End With
                    Next
                Next n
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Exit For 'done checking?
             End If
        Next m
        file = Dir
    Wend

End Sub
```